# `install': undefined method `register_postprocessor' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sprockets, autoprefixer

I get this exception when I start rails server and also on assets precompile

```
/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/autoprefixer-rails-4.0.2.2/lib/autoprefixer-rails/sprockets.rb:20:in `install': undefined method `register_postprocessor' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.17'

ruby '2.0.0'
```

What could be the cause of this error?

Comment: By the way, you should upgrade to Rails 3.2.21 because of security upgrades.

Comment: https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer/issues/305 update autopixer

Answer (score 0):

I think the cause of such error is that you have disabled the assets, try to set it to true, into you **config/environments/production.rb** or **config/application.rb**

```
# Enable the asset pipeline
config.assets.enabled = true
```